# MySql query to retrieve post_title, content, featured image link from a wordpress database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have been trying for quite a long time to retrieve post_title, post_content and feature image link for all posts BASED ON A particular CATEGORY, from a wordpress database. (I will do a JSON parsing to populate android listview with featured img and post title)

I have got a query:

```
SELECT
    p1.post_title,p1.post_content,
    wm2.meta_value
FROM
    wp_posts p1
LEFT JOIN
    wp_postmeta wm1
    ON (
        wm1.post_id = p1.id
        AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
        AND wm1.meta_key = "_thumbnail_id"
    )
LEFT JOIN
    wp_postmeta wm2
    ON (
        wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id
        AND wm2.meta_key = "_wp_attached_file"
        AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL
    )
WHERE
    p1.post_status="publish"
    AND p1.post_type="post"
ORDER BY
    p1.post_date DESC
```

This works fine but it doesnt get me the result based on a particular category.

Can someone please help me to get the featured images for all posts based on a particular category

eg: lets say wp_term_taxonomy.term_id =48

Please Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT p1.*, wm2.meta_value 
FROM wp_posts p1 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wm1 ON (
    wm1.post_id = p1.id
    AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
    AND wm1.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
)
LEFT JOIN
wp_postmeta wm2
ON (
    wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id
    AND wm2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
    AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL
)
LEFT JOIN
wp_term_relationships wtr
ON (
    object_id=p1.id
)
WHERE
p1.post_status='publish'
AND p1.post_type='post'
AND `term_taxonomy_id`=?
ORDER BY p1.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: I tried something like that and got it worked. Anyway, Thank you so much!